ARCore: Raw Depth Codelab not running
I'm using the ARCore Raw Depth code lab: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/arcore-rawdepthapi.
I didn't edit any of the code and I'm running the first part of the Code lab, part0_work, which is supposed to be an empty app that doesn't do anything but access the camera.
Initially I had errors that my Java version and Gradle version didn't match, so I upgraded Gradle to 7.2 - My Java version is 17. There aren't any issues building the app now, but when I run part0_work, I get the following errors:
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':part0_work:processDebugManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @14bc7502

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

(I personally omitted errors here because it didn't fit in StackOverflows limit)

==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':part0_work:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':part0_work:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
   > Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, C:\Users\dparakal\Documents\StudioProjects\arcore-rawdepthapi\part0_work\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out)) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@259aa838) before task ':part0_work:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':part0_work:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.DefaultTaskProperties.resolve(DefaultTaskProperties.java:83)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveMutations(LocalTaskNode.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.getResolvedMutationInfo(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:665)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.selectNext(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:577)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$executeNextNode$1(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.resources.DefaultResourceLockCoordinationService.withStateLock(DefaultResourceLockCoordinationService.java:45)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:155)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$PropertyQueryException: Failed to calculate the value of task ':part0_work:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.finalizeNow(AbstractProperty.java:239)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.beforeRead(AbstractProperty.java:230)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.calculateOwnValueNoProducer(AbstractProperty.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$AbstractFileVar.access$100(DefaultFilePropertyFactory.java:180)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$AbstractFileVar$2.calculateOwnValue(DefaultFilePropertyFactory.java:263)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.getOrNull(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.FileParameterUtils.resolveOutputFilePropertySpecs(FileParameterUtils.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.OutputUnpacker.visitOutputFileProperty(OutputUnpacker.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.CompositePropertyVisitor.visitOutputFileProperty(CompositePropertyVisitor.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.annotations.AbstractOutputPropertyAnnotationHandler.visitPropertyValue(AbstractOutputPropertyAnnotationHandler.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.visitProperties(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.NestedRuntimeBeanNode.visitNode(NestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.DefaultPropertyWalker.visitProperties(DefaultPropertyWalker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskPropertyUtils.visitProperties(TaskPropertyUtils.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.DefaultTaskProperties.resolve(DefaultTaskProperties.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveMutations(LocalTaskNode.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.getResolvedMutationInfo(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:665)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.selectNext(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:577)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$executeNextNode$1(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.resources.DefaultResourceLockCoordinationService.withStateLock(DefaultResourceLockCoordinationService.java:45)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:155)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, C:\Users\dparakal\Documents\StudioProjects\arcore-rawdepthapi\part0_work\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out)) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@259aa838) before task ':part0_work:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.lambda$beforeRead$0(TransformBackedProvider.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.ValueSupplier$TaskProducer.visitContentProducerTasks(ValueSupplier.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.beforeRead(TransformBackedProvider.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.MappingProvider.calculateOwnValue(MappingProvider.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.withFinalValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.finalValue(DefaultProperty.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.finalValue(DefaultProperty.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.finalizeNow(AbstractProperty.java:236)
    ... 27 more

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

I'm not sure if I should deprecate Java or upgrade Gradle or if the issue is something else entirely.
UPDATE: I tried updating Gradle, it didn't work. Also I can't deprecate Java anymore since Java 13 isn't free (The java version for Gradle 6.1.1)

How are you testing? Device or emulator.

Device - It's a Samsung Galaxy Tab S9+. I checked and it supports the Depth API and ARCore.
